# Wrong display dropdown menu (mobile) bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

my problem is on this pic:
[image]

On mobile view have the same dropdown list like normal screen.

Code Here:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default   box-centered" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid menu-box">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">"logo here"</a>
    </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav nav-justified menu" style="margin:0 auto;">
              <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">List ext <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="text-padding"><a href="#">something</a></li>
            <li class="text-padding"><a href="#">other</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="text-padding"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li class="text-padding"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        <li class="text-padding"><a href="#">Fouuur</a></li>


      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

My classes for those elements from stylesheet:
http://pastebin.com/HUUShLNQ

I want to menu look like this, with each element under previous:
[image]
Can you help me solve this?

Comment: You did not describe your problem!

Comment: sorry, I'm edited post

Comment: Any links to the online version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1ummyodw/1/

you have removed **navbar-nav** class from navigation ul so if you add that this will work, Updated HTML snippet:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default   box-centered" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid menu-box">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">"logo here"</a>
        </div>


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-justified menu" style="margin:0 auto;">
             <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">List ext <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu text-center" role="menu">
                <li class="text-padding"><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li class="text-padding"><a href="#">other</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="text-padding"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li class="text-padding"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            <li class="text-padding"><a href="#">Fouuur</a></li>


          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```